# How to get Linux version, using /etc listing?

Tags: java, linux

I want to get Linux version using this code:

```
public void getSystemVersion()
    {
        File f = new File("/etc/");
        File[] allReleaseFiles = f.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
            {
                System.out.println("System Verison : " + name.endsWith("-release"));
                return name.endsWith("-release");
            }
        });
    }
```

But this is the output that I get:

```
.......
System Verison : false
System Verison : false
System Verison : false
System Verison : false
System Verison : false
System Verison : false
System Verison : false
........
```

Can you help me to find the problem?
Also how I can do this using Java 8 code?

Comment: (Do any of the files end with "-release"? Check with `ls /etc/*-release`. If so, are they world readable?)

Comment: try `uname -a` command instead!

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "Linux version"? The kernel version, the version of the Linux distribution, ...

Comment: `uname -r` gives you just what you want, if you want the kernel version.

Comment: my /etc/ on debian contains, "/etc/lsb-release  /etc/os-release
" and on gentoo contains "/etc/gentoo-release  /etc/os-release"... and there could be any number of other extraneous results in there... I would trust the `uname` returns more... Or [synthomat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2938389/synthomat)'s answer...

Comment: Can you help me to fix my code?

Answer (score 1):

Try to parse `/proc/version`. It's the same as calling `uname -r`. At least you don't have to mess with processes.